# with a bq24190 charging IC how can I feed the usb bus when in host mode (OTG)

Tags: usb, stm32, battery-charging

I'm fairly new to this and I am trying to build a board around a `stm32f750z8` and I'm on the USB OTG/charging part.

The board will have only one USB port in OTG mode, and the mcu will be powered by the battery/usb, no other external power, the external device (in host mode) can be an HID peripheral, flash disk, etc. and will be powered by the board. In device mode, the board will be powered by USB (and charging the battery).

I've found the `bq24190` IC that can handle USB OTG and battery charging but I have issues understanding how to manage the "usb host" condition (delivering power to the usb device connected, from the battery).

I have wired the USB `VBUS` to the stm32 `USB_OTG_FS_VBUS` pin (PA9) which seems to allow detection of device vs host, but I can't figure how to powers the USB `VBUS` if I want to like use a flash drive in OTG.

I have seen others stm32 mcus with an usb otg enable pin, used to trigger a power switch, but here I'm lost at what I should do.

The bq IC does have an input pin `OTG` that can trigger a boost mode but I can't figure what that means exactly here.

So my big question is how can I powers the USB BUS while in host mode and not in device mode ?

Here is the actual schematic of the power part:
[image: circuit of the power part]

Comment: I'm a bit confused: Which of the devices are USB hosts, which are USB peripherals, and who is supposed to power whom?

Comment: The board with the STM32 will be either device or host, and for devices that can be an hid device, flash disk, whatever. And the device connected to the board via USB should be powered by the board.

Comment: Coucou @dashie good luck with your device :)